# Узнать версию файла перед скачиванием

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

Пишу что-то вроде лаунчера для своего приложения, который бы скачивал с сервера более актуальную версию приложения. Попал в тупик на моменте определения версии.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно узнать версию исполняемого файла, находящегося на сервере, не скачивая его?

Сейчас у меня на сервере в папке лежит приложение и текстовый документ, в котором записана версия. Лаунчер скачивает файл и читает из него версию, если текущая версия отличается от серверной, то происходит загрузка. Но это в крайней степени не красиво и подходит только для первоначального тестирования.

Comment: Как вариант можно в том же .txt файле хранить не только версию лаунчера, но и имена всех файлов с датой последнего изменения (версией).

Или через заголовок Content-Length получать размер файла и сравнивать с тем что имеется сейчас.

Comment: @walik, я тоже думал о сравнении по размеру файла. Тем более, что крутое логирование мне не нужно, ибо программу используют полтора землекопа в пределах одного офиса, и этот лаунчер я делаю исключительно для себя, чтобы постоянно вручную не делать обновления на машинах.

Comment: а размер файла может и совпадать. Никто ведь ему не мешает.

Comment: @KoVadim, не спорю. Но на первое время такой конструкции мне вполне хватит. Со временем сделаю что-нибудь более практичное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно так и делают - лежит тексовый (xml, json, yaml)  с указанием текущей версии, лога изменений и подобным.

Но можно сделать через редирект. То есть, запрос идет на один адрес, а там обычный http редирект, который редиректит на правильный адрес бинарника, куда в названия включена версия.

Answer (score 2):

Это нормально -- узнавать версию файла до его загрузки!

Вот пример типичной и достаточно эффективной модели обновления как ПО так и других данных.

1. ПО подлежащее обновлению хранит номер версии в конкретном месте ( диск, реестр, внутри себя... )
2. Сервер обновления принимает сетевые запросы на проверку обновлений. ( простые TCP, усложнённые HTTP или что угодно ). Тут могут быть усложнения. например в запросе можно передавать текущую версию ПО, а сервер готовит специально для текущей версии пакет обновлений или же просто возвращает самую последнюю версию.
3. Апдейтер ( или Лаунчер ) посылает запрос на сервер и проверяет текущую версию ПО если совпадает то всё хорошо иначе обновляет.